# Is there a way to keep headers aligned correctly while using both filter and scrollX in Shiny datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have many columns in my shiny app and need to keep an option of scrolling horizontally. I need to use 'filter' option as well. For some reason when using both options and opening the app **in a Browser**, the column names are aligned incorrectly (not placed above the corresponding column values).
Below the code example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
    h2("The mtcars data"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(cbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars), 
                  filter = "top",
                  options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Colnames are aligned correctly when we removing the scrollX options (however it is not a solution for me, I need to keep the possibility of horizontal scrolling).
I know it used to be a common issue but wondering if anyone has managed to fix it so far.

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359344/r-shiny-shifted-column-names-with-datatable) might help.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me- I think the main problem here is need of keeping the problematic filter = "top" argument. When opening in a browser all filter fields have same width, while columns have various widths, which causing a mismatch...